# Admob Interstitial ad on a Button Click

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'am making an app in android studio with kotlin, I tried to add interstitial ad to it when a button clicked ad shows up, and using `onAdClosed()` method the second activity shows up after the ad closed, the problem is that the app keeps crushing in main activity 2 sometimes 3.
this is how my code look like

```js
private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
private lateinit var adRequest : AdRequest

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")

    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"


    requestNewInterstitial()
    button2.setOnClickListener{
        val intent1 = Intent(this,Main2Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent1)
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        } else {
        }
        mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial()
                //go to second activity or do something
            }
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                requestNewInterstitial()

            }
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(i: Int) {

                requestNewInterstitial()


            }

        }
    }
}
private fun requestNewInterstitial() {
    adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)}
```

I want when the user clicks on button the ad should be seen and when he closes the ad he should go to second activity

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712")
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked()
        }

        override fun onAdClosed() {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SecondActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    btn.setOnClickListener {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the onClosed function it will help me for sure.

Comment: if this code is helpful to you, please check as correct answer.

Comment: Your code is missing the onAdFailedToLoad function and doesn't request another ad after the interstitial show up but you rally helped me with the onClosed function.